# How to double click to tick a checkbox?

Tags: html

I use a Shopping List with a changeStatus function to update an element on click. Elements are automatically filtered (non ticked at the top). Sometimes I missclick on an element so it becomes ticked and is automatically filtered and then instantly disapears in the bottom of my list so I could not even know what element has been ticked (too bad when doing shopping...).

I would like to prevent this by having a mandatory double click to tick/untick element, but I don't know how to deal with it with checkbox.

```
<fieldset class="items-list">
        <label class="items-list-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter : filterItem">
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            value="{{item.STATUS}}"
            ng-checked="item.STATUS==2"
            ng-click="changeStatus(item.ID,item.STATUS,item.ITEM)"
            class="items-list-cb"/>
            <span class="items-list-mark"></span>
            <span class="items-list-desc" ng-class="{strike:item.STATUS==2}">{{item.ITEM}}</span> 
            <a ng-click="deleteItem(item.ID)" class="pull-right red"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a> 
        </label>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: You should instead add a button to confirm the fact that the user wants to filter. Using this, you will be able, in the future, to add more filtering options.

Comment: I like the auto-filter function, so unticked items are automatically at the top of the list (see screenshot http://www.noelshack.com/2019-28-2-1562706343-sans-titre.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below ignores the single click with the help of `onclick="return false"` and toggles the tick on double click with the help of `ondblclick="this.checked = !this.checked"`

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" ondblclick="this.checked = !this.checked" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I cannot made it work. I had both parameters in the input but it is not working, still ticking with simple click. I also tried to move the changeStatus function from the ng-click to the ondblclick but same result as above.

Comment: OK I managed to make it work by displaying the original checkbox (that is not displayed usually, cf https://www.noelshack.com/2019-28-3-1562790575-sans-titre.png). The double check works fine on the initial checkbox but not on the others parts of the item (displayed checkbox and name) that usually work for the single click.

Comment: @FlorianGATE, this question was `How to double click to tick a checkbox?`. You need to ask another question to make it work on label and images.

Comment: Also, don't forget to put the code you used to bind the images and label to the checkbox

Comment: Thank you very much! I added an answer to display the code for now :)

Comment: Is everything working now or you have more question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dbl").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(".dbl").dblclick(function(e) {
    let myCheckbox = $("input[type=checkbox]", this);
    myCheckbox.prop("checked", !myCheckbox.prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="dbl"><input class="dbl" type="checkbox">double click to tick/untick element</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by adding onclick and ondblclick to the input tag. When clicked, the onclick removes the check, but if double-clicked the ondblclick adds the check.

```html
<p>Double-click ads a check, while single click removes the check.</p>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.checked = false" ondblclick="this.checked = true">
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I cannot made it work. I had both parameters in the input but it is not working, still ticking with simple click. I also tried to move the changeStatus function from the ng-click to the ondblclick but same result as above.

Comment: @Steve Lage, This is your original code. You should not edit your answer with my answer

Comment: @LIGHT I did not edit my answer with yours.  YOU suggested an edit to my answer, which I accepted. All I did was accept your suggested edit. Afterwards you added an answer which matched your suggested edit. I edited the wording to more accurately describe the code of your suggested edit. That's exactly what happened.

Comment: nope, @ksiger edited your answer, check edit history. I just rolled back your answer